# Is there an Android Studio setting that has predictive or auto-complete behavior?

Tags: android-studio

I used an IDE once and when I'd type a word in parentheses and then hit TAB, the system would put the cursor behind the parentheses. I found this very useful.  Is there some type of setting like this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. It auto-completes the control structure you're currently typing. Not exactly what you're asking for, but close (IMO better).

For example when you're typing an `if` and you have something like this:

```
if (foo == 5|)
```

(`|` here signifies cursor position) you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and it's autocompleted to

```
if (foo == 5) {
    |
}
```

Works for ifs, loops, switch-cases, functions...